# How to automatically split a content into 2 rows without div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a div where users can enter some content and the content length should spread only up to 300px(from LHS) and height 100px. If the content is more than that, it should start showing it in rest of space (RHS as shown in image). I don't want to create multiple divs since it is a CMS where users just enter the text as they wish and it should automatically spread content to 2nd div after filling certain height. Can it be achieved without scripts? I`m trying to avoid the scripts as much as possible

[image: content splitting as per image]

Here is the code I tried so far. But only able to wrap for one row. not 2nd one

```css
div{
width:300px;
max-height:100px; 
overflow:hidden;
text-align:justify;
word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
```

Comment: remove width and add `column-count:2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what CSS columns are for:

```
div {
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 300px;
}
```

You can read up on it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns

Comment: Works like charm. Never came across css columns concept untill now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The `column-count` property specifies the number of columns an element should be divided into.

Just add `column-count:2` as style for your div.

```css
div{
column-count:2 
 
}
```

```html
<div>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
```

Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp)